# How to model a many-to-one sqlalchemy relationship for every df upload in one table to generate a row in another sql table

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.11

I wan't to model a many to one relationship with sql alchemy.

I want to upload a df to a sqlalchemy sqlite table. This df contains per every upload a contant uuid (multiple rows with same uuid per upload.

After this upload I wan't to create a row in another sql table with this same uuid. This Table should contain a unique autoincrement primary key, this uuid, a timestamp and a comment.

Why I wan't to do something like this?

- The App pushes various hundred rows per upload and I wan't to have another table, to have a better overview to check when an upload occured. It may happen, that an upload happens twice. So it would be confortable to have a second table for one row with uuid and timestamp for every upload.

I have something like this in mind as the db model

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, DateTime, Index
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app import cfg

Base = declarative_base()

table1 = cfg["db"]["customnumbers"]["table1"]

class Metainformations(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Metainformationen"
    miid = Column("MIID", Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    comment = Column("Kommentar", String)
    timestamp = Column("Zeitstempel", ForeignKey(f"{table1}.Zeitstempel"))
    # uuid = Column("UUIDs", String(36))
    uuid = relationship("CustomnumberTable", back_populates="uuids")
    # author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('authors.id'))


class CustomnumberTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = table1
    # mznaid = maersk zollnummern auftrags id
    mznaid = Column("MZNAID", Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column("Zeitstempel", DateTime)
    leNummer = Column("LE-Nummer", String(16))
    zollregistrierungsnr = Column("Zollregistrierungsnr", String(26))
    errorType = Column("errorType", String)
    auftragNrAG = Column("AuftragNrAG", Integer, index=True)
    auftragNr = Column("AuftragNr", String(10), index=True)
    boxXStatus = Column("BoxXStatus", String)
    rid = Column("RID", String(1))
    datum = Column("Datum", String(10))
    refNrAG = Column("RefNrAG", String(11))
    metazüge = Column("Metazüge", String(21))
    produkt = Column("Produkt", String(6))
    uuids = Column("UUIDs", String(36))
```

For the Data Processing something in this direction.

```
db = dbConnection(db_filename=cfg["db"]["customnumbers"]["db_name"])
db_engine = db.db_engine
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)

customnumber_table = cfg["db"]["customnumbers"]["table1"]
uuid_var = uuid.uuid1()
df_invoice["UUIDs"] = str(uuid_var)
df_invoice = df_invoice[cfg["db"]["customnumbers"]["cols"]]

df_invoice.to_sql(
  customnumber_table, db_engine, if_exists="append", index=False
)
# # # from app.db_model import Metainformations, customnumberTable
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
session = Session()

new_uuid = Metainformations(uuid=uuid_var)
session.add(new_uuid)
session.commit()
```

Obviously it does not work and I don't know what I have to do, hehe.

Thank you all in advance,

Regards brazil91